# kylo ingestion feed error

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I am new to Kylo.

I manually deployed Kylo on a test cluster of Hortonworks HDP 2.5 and have reused my Nifi instance prior to kylo.

I made a sample feed by following like ingestion tutorial (User Signups) and was successful.

However, when I drop sample data file in /var/dropzone/ the file is removed (assuming it is fetched and read by Nifi) but the operational dashboard does not show any any job running. No status against the feed job is populated.

I looked at the generated nifi process flow and there are two red processes and both are **ReleaseHighWaterMark** processes.
Also, Upon checking nifi-app.log I found following exception

```
2017-05-25 16:42:51,939 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.t.n.p.ProvenanceEventCollector ERROR PROCESSING EVENT! ProvenanceEventRecordDTO{eventId=759716, processorName=null, componentId=01a84157-0b38-14f2-d63d-c41fbd9c38a3, flowFile=ab93de46-e659-4c41-9812-94bbe2f90cfc, previous=null, eventType=CREATE, eventDetails=null, isEndOfJob=false, isBatch=true, isStream=false, feed=null}.  ERROR: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

It seems there is a configuration issue and there is hardly any good troubleshooting guide available.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Please check that the KyloPrevenanceEventReportingTask is running in NiFi: http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/NiFiKyloProvenanceReportingTask.html

If that doesn't resolve the issue, please post the stack trace that accompanies the error message.

Comment: thaks @Greg. I simply restarted Nifi and Kylo and error disappeared. Strange!!